# Bigquery and Google Sheets Integration

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I'm trying to automate a result from query in a google sheets. To do that I'm using a script from Ido Green that he posted on your blog. It works perfectly, but I need to extend his powers, since I need to be able to read a cell and use the value as an argument on my query. The cell value will be a value on where condition. I tried some solutions, but since I'm not an expert on Apps Script, didn't work. A fragment of Ido's script:

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sql = 'select TOP(word, 30), COUNT(*) as word_count from publicdata:samples.shakespeare WHERE LENGTH(word) > 10;';
  var queryResults;
  // Inserts a Query Job
  try {
    var queryRequest = BigQuery.newQueryRequest();
    queryRequest.setQuery(sql).setTimeoutMs(100000);
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(queryRequest, projectNumber);
  }
  catch (err) {
    Logger.log(err);
    Browser.msgBox(err);
    return;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this for example you can control the minimum length of the word by changing `Sheet1!C1`

```
var limit = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName("Sheet1")
    .getRange("C1")
    .getValue();

var sql = 'select TOP(word, 30), COUNT(*) as word_count from publicdata:samples.shakespeare WHERE LENGTH(word) > ' + limit + ';';
```